# how can I make a .py file run from my LKM in C

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-device-driver

so I have this C code for a Linux kernel module, the final goal is to have a python script run at the press of a button. I am able to make an led switch off with the button, so I know that works. I have this function

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/gpio.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>

***
all the code for the interrupt handler to turn led on when button pressed. This is where  execute_pthon() is called
***

void execute_python(){

char * paramsList[] = { "/bin/bash", "-c",
                        "/usr/bin/python /home/pi/pysql.py", NULL };
        execv("/bin/bash",paramsList); // python system call

}
```

All I want this to do is make a python script run on my pi. Same action as doing 'python pysql.py' in the command line.

However, whenever I make the file all I get is

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rpisrc/linux'
  CC [M]  /home/Desktop/piirq/piirq.o
/home/Desktop/piirq/piirq.c:76:6: error: function declaration isn't a prototype [-Werror=strict-prototypes]
 void execute_python(){
      ^
/home/Desktop/piirq/piirq.c: In function 'execute_python':
/home/Desktop/piirq/piirq.c:80:9: error: implicit declaration of function 'execv' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
         execv("/bin/bash",paramsList); // python system call
         ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:266: /home/Desktop/piirq/piirq.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1709: /home/Desktop/piirq] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rpisrc/linux'
make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2
```

Comment: You miss a declaration for `execute_python` and I think you miss an inlcude for `execv` I recommand to not use execv and code the C code equivalent to your python

Comment: Im connecting and writing to a sql database, cant really do that here. need the specific python libraries

Comment: running in kernel land this is strange, you can take a look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355951/issue-running-process-from-a-linux-kernel-module and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372912/hooking-sys-execve-on-linux-3-x/9672512#9672512

Comment: If I was to run it in userspace, how would I communicate with the userspace that a button has been pressed from the LKM?

Comment: My Hosh, the correct way is to use input driver for your button and subscribe to an event in the user space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute shell command in kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193648/execute-shell-command-in-kernel-module)